# angularjs - Append method to created service

Tags: angularjs

I have a generic service that returns a resource and need to append new methods to this on another services. Is this possible?

```
app.factory('FooFactory', function ($resource) {
    var model = $resource(
        '/:controller/:action/:id', 
        { controller: '@controller', id: '@id' }, 
        { 'foo': { method: 'GET', params: { action: 'foo' } }
    });

    return model;
});

app.factory('BarFactory', function ($resource, FooFactory) {
    var model = FooFactory;
    model.bar = ???

    return model;
});
```

Comment: Is FooFactory same as FooService, or are there three players involved?

Comment: My mistake, question edited

Comment: You cannot do that (and it doesn't make much sense either). Ae you sur you want to extend the same resource and not create a new one ?

Comment: Because I need Bar inherit Foo

Comment: Well, what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
app.factory('FooFactory', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    var foo = $resource('/:controller/:action/:id', 
        { controller: '@controller', id: '@id' },
        { 'foo': { method: 'GET', params: { action: 'foo' } } }
    );

    var getFoo = function() {
        return foo;
    };

    return {
        getFoo: getFoo
    };
}]);

app.factory('BarFactory', [ 'FooFactory', function(FooFactory) {
    var foo = FooFactory.getFoo();
    // not totally clear what your goal is here
    // if bar is just part of foo
    // foo.bar = {};
    // if bar is like foo but then you want to modify things
    var bar = $.extend(true, {}, foo); // with jQuery
    // var bar = _.cloneDeep(foo); // lodash way

    var getBar = function() {
        return bar; // or foo.bar if it is just a part of foo
    };

    return {
        getBar: getBar
    };
}]);
```

If the goal is to modify the foo returned by the FooFactory then perhaps a setter type function in FooFactory would be better, such that BarFactory could do it's computation and call FooFactory.setBar(whatever);